# Can't see my object in Shading tab

Tags: shaders

I'm new to Blender and I'm following a YouTube video to create a Doughnut. Here's my Layout tab:

[image]

In a certain step in the tutorial, the guy selects the object in the Layout tab and then goes to Shading tab and I can see same object there. But in my case a random blurred background is visible. I can't see my object.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The background is supposed to be there - it's the HDRI used for lighting and reflections in Material Preview mode (default for shading tab). The missing item, however is not normal - It might be a few things... possibly GPU related - what kind of GPU do you have and when was the last time you updated your drivers?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett drivers are updated and I have nvidia 940mx gpu.

Comment: Have you tried to focus the view on the object with the *Numpad (period/del/comma)* key? I've just noticed this depends on the keyboard layout. Better use the menu: *View > Frame Selected* if in doubt

Comment: @ChristopherBennett pressing . key did the trick. don't know what happened. However, I scrolled a lot to zoom it out and now it's not visible again. I tried pressing . again but it's not showing. I"m stuck again. so it's not related to gpu at least

Comment: Pressing Numpad-Del(.) centers the camera on the selected object, so I'm guessing you're just too far away. Select the object by name in the _Outliner_ (top-right "window") then put your mouse pointer back in the 3D viewport and press Numpad(.) again.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett done it worked. But I guess it works only once. Can't work continuously if you change the zoom. I can't center camera repeatedly. I had to go to Layout tab again, press . there, then I returned to Shading then pressed . again, then it worked. anyway thanks :)

Comment: I'm assuming you left your donut at world origin. If this is the case you can also bring the camera back it's somewhat "initial" position with Shift+C.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yes it works

Comment: Try pressing forward slash / as you might have entered local mode.

Answer (score 2):

I just recently had this happen. I created new shading tab and the object started showing up in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

go into the view tab next to the selective tab that have object mode and edit mode.

if you hover over view a drop down menu appears go to frame all (5th option) and click on that and your object will re appear :)